# Better way to build multiple conditions in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing with Rails 2.3.8 and looking for a better way to build find conditions.

On search page, like user search,  which user sets search conditions, find conditions are depends on the condition which user have chosen, e.g age, country, zip-code.

I've wrote code below to set multiple find conditions.

```
# Add condition if params post.
conditions_array = []
conditions_array << ['age > ?', params[:age_over]] if params[:age_over].present?
conditions_array << ['country = ?', params[:country]] if params[:country].present?
conditions_array << ['zip_code = ?', params[:zip_code]] if params[:zip_code].present?

# Build condition
i = 0
conditions = Array.new
columns = ''
conditions_array.each do |key, val|
  key = " AND #{key}" if i > 0
  columns += key
  item_master_conditions[i] = val
  i += 1
end
conditions.unshift(columns)
# condiitons => ['age > ? AND country = ? AND zip_code = ?', params[:age], params[country], prams[:zip_code]]

@users = User.find(:all, 
  :conditions => conditions
)
```

This code works fine but it is ugly and not smart.
Is there better way to build find conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Named scopes could make it a bit more readable, albeit bulkier, while still preventing SQL injection.

```
named_scope :age_over, lambda { |age|
  if !age.blank?
    { :conditions => ['age > ?', age] }
  else
    {}
  end
}

named_scope :country, lambda { |country|
  if !country.blank?
    { :conditions => ['country = ?', age] }
  else
    {}
  end
}

named_scope :zip_code, lambda { |zip_code|
  if !zip_code.blank?
    { :conditions => ['zip_code = ?', age] }
  else
    {}
  end
}
```

And then when you do your search, you can simply chain them together:

```
@user = User.age_over(params[:age_over]).country(params[:country]).zip_code(params[:zip_code])
```

Comment: Did you know that in Rails if/else statements can be one-liners :o It is there, well, from the beginning of Ruby. Also what does `else {} end` do? Please don't make such beginner mistakes. Someone will learn the bad approach, just the way you did :/

Answer (score 1):

I have accidentally run on your questions, and even it is old one, here is the answer:

After defining your conditions, you could use it like this:

```
# Add condition if params post.
conditions_array = []
conditions_array << ["age > #{params[:age_over]}"] if params[:age_over].present?
conditions_array << ["country = #{params[:country]}"] if params[:country].present?
conditions_array << ["zip_code = #{params[:zip_code]}"] if params[:zip_code].present?

conditions = conditions_array.join(" AND ")
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => conditions) #Rails 2.3.8
@users = User.where(conditions) #Rails 3+
```

Comment: Rails 2.3.8 doesn't have `.where`.

Comment: Thanks for -1 . When you are so smart, why didn't you post your answer instead? I have updated answer for both versions.

Comment: While this is much more concise, it opens up the possibility of SQL injection. As it turns out, I found this thread because I'm trying to fix some code almost just like this.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer to overcome that problem. thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. Assuming `params[:age_over]` = 21 and `params[:country]` = "US" and `params[:zip_code]` = "90210", the resulting SQL statement is `SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE (users.age > ? AND 21 AND users.country = ? AND US AND users.zip_code = ? AND 90210);` which results in an ActiveRecord error.

Comment: @AlexanderClark please don't pretend that you are the smartest man on the world and please don't use word `"this doesn't work either"` and pretending that you are very smart, as the previous solutions worked and don't underestimate the answers. I have tried to update it to make it better. I have updated your answer as well, but you are so narrow-minded that you don't want to accept update and let other decide which solution they like the best.

Comment: This allows sql inject

Comment: @ArnoldRoa That is not true. The sole purpose of escaping `#{}` like `#{params[:age_over]}` is to overcome sql inject and safely pass user `params` (at least for Rails 2), but thanks for posting comment without a real suggestion.